# In what cases will mongo generate an unique ID

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Let's say i have a mongoose schema with the following format :

```
experience: [
    {
      title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      company: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      location: {
        type: String
      },
      from: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
      },
      to: {
        type: Date
      },
      current: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
      },
      description: {
        type: String
      }
    }
  ]
```

Experience is an array that holds objects. Now my question is, does the object that gets passed into this array get an unique ID? And why is this, it's not a separate schema it's just an object in an array. In what cases will you get 
an unique ID be generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation: [**`mongoose`**](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html)

> Mongoose has two distinct notions of subdocuments: arrays of
>   subdocuments and single nested subdocuments.
>   And each **subdocument** has an **`_id`** by default.

So every creation of **subdocument** either using **`push`** or **`create`** [adding subdocs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html#adding-subdocs-to-arrays) will result in creation of unique `_id` for that sub-document.

**When it will not generate that `_id` for those sub-documents?:**

By explicitly defining `{ _id : false }` in the sub-schema. For example in this case:

```
experience: [
    {
      _id: false,
      title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      company: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      location: {
        type: String
      },
      from: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
      },
      to: {
        type: Date
      },
      current: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
      },
      description: {
        type: String
      }
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer after doing research.

The short answer is, what you see in my structure is an array of "[documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/cpp/documents/)"

Every document in mongoDB will have its own unique ID, this is why an ID is generated in the above example everytime a new document is inserted. This id can be used to delete or update the document in the future.

Comment: Sub-documents don't need to have an _id, this applies only to documents in a collection. These get a unique _id.
Of course you provide an explicit _id in every sub-document, too. But this is not automatically by Mongo.